# Saving foreach output as a string variable?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am looping through a SQL query and I would like to grab that output and save it as a string variable.. is this possible?

My loop is as follows:

```
 foreach ($dbh->query($sql2) as $row2) {
        echo $row2['id'];
        echo $row2['staff'];
        echo $row2['dept'];
    }
```

And I would like to save all of the output as one string variable ie `$output`

Comment: Please be more specific about the format of `$output`

Comment: I would like $output to be a variable that holds all of the looped through data. "1,Joe Smith,Finance,2,Bob Smith,Finance" etc.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. [Did you not read up on string operations](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)?

Comment: As soon as I read dianuj's answer I realized how simple of a answer this was. Oh well, live and learn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$output="";

foreach ($dbh->query($sql2) as $row2) {
   $output.= $row2['id'];
   $output.= $row2['staff'];
   $output.= $row2['dept'];
}
```

you can append the each coloumn result

```
echo $output
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking into output buffering.

```
ob_start();
foreach ($dbh->query($sql2) as $row2) {
        echo $row2['id'];
        echo $row2['staff'];
        echo $row2['dept'];
    }
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

[Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Answer (score 0):

use implode and if you want turn String to Array use explode

```
$output=implode(',', $dbh->query($sql2));
```

The first argument is optional
And any tokens you put in are separated by the array members
for example :

```
$ar = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
echo implode($ar); // abcdefg
$ar = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
echo implode(',',$ar); // a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```